# ASP.NET DataView error

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, dataview

I'm having some trouble with a DataView in ASP.NET. My code is pretty simple, I just want to pull information from an MS Access table called COURSEINFO, put the information into a DataSet, and use a DataView as the source of a GridView. I realize that it would be easier to just use an SQL Data Source to populate the GridView, but I want to use the DataView so that I can expand it later.

However, this line of code gives me a compile error:

dv = dv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView

where dv is my DataView and ds is my DataSet. The error occurs after the "=", dv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView appears underlined in blue.

Oddly, this code worked for me a few days ago, and I don't know why is doesn't anymore. The error that I get says: "Value of type 'System.Data.DataView' cannot be converted to 'WebApplication1.DataView'

Here's my code:

```
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;" & "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\EXSpring2014.accdb")
    Dim command As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String = "Select * from COURSEINFO"
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim dv As DataView

    connection.Open()
    command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
    adapter.SelectCommand = command
    adapter.Fill(ds, "Create_DataView")
    adapter.Dispose()
    command.Dispose()
    connection.Close()
    dv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView

        GridView1.DataSource = dv
```

When I actually try to load the web form, I get an error in the HTML code. I you would like to see it, the URL is
http://ime1.ime.calpoly.edu/ime312_move1x/ime312_5/WebApplication1/camtasia.aspx

Finally, while working on this, I generated a method stub that I didn't end up needing for "DataView". I'm thinking that this might be a cause, but I don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

The red herring is the error:

> "Value of type 'System.Data.DataView' cannot be converted to 'WebApplication1.DataView'

What does the compiler try to explain here?

As the .Net framework adheres strongly typing it requires that developers only assign values to variables that are of the same type. It is understandle that we can't assign a `List<String>` to a `Form`. If you try that you get a similar error you see.

The confusion starts when you name two types the same, in this case `DataView`. You can't have the same named typed **within the same namespace** so there must be two `DataView` types which indeed there are: One in the namespace `System.Data` and one in the namespace `WebApplication1`.

Not seen in your code but I have to assume you created a webpage or another type called `DataView` somewhere in your web project. If the namespace isn't explictely specified the compiler asssumes the type that is in the current namespace should be used.

To solve this compile error you simply have to be excplicit which `DataView` you want a variable to be.

Change the type of your `dv` to be of type `System.Data.DataView` and all should be fine:

```
Dim dv As System.Data.DataView
```

Have a read on the artcile [Namespaces in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx) for some more background.